# Firebase database. Find a position in the node by record id

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my app I have some videos and users can like it. video metadata saves in the node "videos", something like this:

```
videos: {   
    xxxxx: {
      name: "Funny video",
      likes: 255,
      ....
    }
}
```

And I have another node "userVideos" only with video ids.

```
userVideos: {   
    xxxxx: true,
    yyyyy: true,
```

}

In the UI I want to show the ranking of the video. For example, I have 5 videos: v01 has 5 likes, v02 - 10, v03 - 1, v04 - 100, v05 - 3.

So, when I get from userVideos the video with id "v03", I should know that his ranking is 5 ('cause if I get the videos list with orderBy DESC my videos node, the position of v03 is 5).

I think that the cloud function should calculate this ranking. 
My question is next: is I have a possibility to get the position in the sorted node by key?

Answer (score 0):

Realtime Database queries can't tell you the position of a child snapshot in a sorted query.  You have to write code to maintain that data for yourself.

Comment: Like Doug said, you cant find the position of a child in a sorted query, but what you can do is just orderBy video views or video likes, that should do the trick to order those videos by ranking, you can have different video categories and just order each categorie by views or likes

Comment: It should be global ranking by all videos. 
As I understand, the firebase cloud storage doesn't support "indexOf()" too?

Comment: That is correct: neither the Firebase Realtime Database, nor Cloud Storage for Firebase, nor Cloud Firestore supports retrieving item by index, or determining the index of an item. The reason for this is that such an operation inherently limits the scalability of the system, since you must know the (in this case) number of likes of all videos to know the index/ranking of one video.